# Como agregar elementos a un Array en Java?

Tags: java

El problema que estoy teniendo es que tengo un array con un determinado tamaño y en el mismo se van a ir agregando elementos pero no puedo hacerlo de la forma tradicional ya que el sistema no va a saber cual es la posición siguiente.

```
public class Equipo{

    private String nombre;
    private int a=0;
    private int b=0;
    private Jugador titulares[]=new Jugador[a];
    private Jugador suplentes[]=new Jugador[b];

    public String getNombre(){
        return nombre;
    }
    public setNombre(String nombre){
        this.nombre=nombre;
    }

}
```

El tema es que tengo la clase Jugadores y la clase Equipo, en el cual en la clase Equipo tengo 2 array suplentes y titulares entre ambos tanto suplentes como titulares suman 30 por eso cree las variables a y b para controlar eso , pero el tema es que tengo que hacer una operacion **agregarTitular(Jugador j1){}**, pero dentro de esa función no se como agregar el jugador que recibo por parámetros a el array Titulares.

Comment: Esto parece un ejercicio no? podrias poner las restricciones que tenes?

Comment: ¿Es decir que quieres hacer un arreglo dinámico en cuanto al tamaño?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

usando como referencia [este tutorial](http://www.sc.ehu.es/sbweb/fisica/cursoJava/fundamentos/clases1/arays.htm)

tenemos que:

```
tipo_de_dato[] nombre_del_array;
```

esto nos define el array por ejemplo en tu caso

```
Jugador titulares[];
```

ahora eso esta bien pero tenemos in pequenio problema en la forma en que crea el array

1. `private int a=0; 
    private Jugador titulares[]=new Jugador[a];`

esto es lo mismo que decir:
    `private Jugador titulares[]=new Jugador[0];`
osea creamos un array de jugadores que no puede contener jugadores por que es de tamano `0` y en este caso no es ideal. por que no podemos agregar nada. en este caso sujiero en el contructor recibir o determinar la cantidad de campos que seran necesarios reservar en este `array`

ahora para applicar o crear `agregarTitular(Jugador j1)` se me ocuren 2... tal ves 3 formas de hacerlo. esto dependera mucho de como quieras que funcione. voy a sugerir 2 formas.

1. `agregarTitular(Jugador j1)` agrega a los jugadores conforme se
   ingresan por tanto el primer jugador queda en la posición `0`
   (recuerde array inicia de 0) y asi hasta llegar a la posicion
   `titulares.lenght -1` (el ultimo valor que puede agregar) y cuando ya este lleno   no permita agregar mas? o decir false? eso depende de usted...
2. `agregarTitular(Jugador j1, int posicion)` agrega o remplasa a un jugador en la posicion que se provee de forma que `titulares[posicion] = j1` si ya hay un jugador en `titulares[posicion]` este es remplasado por  `j1` **PERO** en este caso debes verificar que `posicion` sea un index valido

en este caso para agregar un elemento en el array lo que tenemos que hacer es:

```
public class Equipo{

    private String nombre;
    //aque SOLO se define las variables no se inicializan (crean)
    private Jugador titulares[];
    private Jugador suplentes[];

    /**
    * el contructor de esta clase crea un nuevo objeto el parametro ntitulares
    * nos define cuantos titulares va a tener el parametro nsuplentes nos
    * define cuantos suplentes va a tener
    *
    * @param nequipo nombre inicial
    * @param ntitulares cuantos titulares va a tener
    * @param nsuplentes cuantos suplentes va a tener
    */
    public Equipo(String nequipo,int ntitulares, int nsuplentes){
        //...
        //agregar codigo aqui que verificque que 
        //ntitulares + nsuplentes == 30 
        // y que maneje los esenario donde ntitulares + nsuplentes != 30
        // o disparar error? eso depende de OP
        //...
        //se le asigna el nombre del equipo
        nombre = nequipo;
        //se crea y asigna un array a titulares del tamano ntitulares
        titulares = new Jugador[ntitulares];
        //se crea y asigna un array a suplentes del tamano nsuplentes
        suplentes = new Jugador[nsuplentes];
    }

    public String getNombre(){
        return nombre;
    }

    // cambia el nombre del equipo
    public void setNombre(String nombre){
        this.nombre=nombre;
    }

    /**
     * metodo 1 agrega el jugador en la posicion que se provee
     *
     * @param j1 el jugador a agregar en la posicion
     * @param posicion la posicion donde va el jugador
     * @return true si se agrego el jugador false si no se puede agregar (la
     * posicion no es valida)
     */
    public boolean agregarTitular(Jugador j1, int posicion) {
        if (posicion >= 0 && posicion < titulares.length) {
            titulares[posicion] = j1;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * metodo 2 agrega el jugador en el array si existe una posision cuyo valor sea nulo (campo vacio)
     * @param j1 jugador a agregar
     * @return true si se pudo agregar false si el array ya esta lleno
     */
    public boolean agregarTitular(Jugador j1) {
        for (int i = 0; i < titulares.length; i++) {
            if (titulares[i] == null) {
                titulares[i] = j1;
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    //para saber cuantos campos hay para titulares
    public int camposTitulares(){
        return titulares.length;
    }

}
```

y ahora como usar esta clase? simple se crear un nuevo objeto equipo:

```
// esto crea un equipo con el nombre "Liga Deportiva X" 
// de 26 jugadores titulares y 4 suplentes
Equipo miEquipo = new Equipo("Liga Deportiva X", 26,4);
```